# Get different parts of a macro argument in C/C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, macros

We know that in macro, we can pass something arbitrary, e.g.

```
#define A(x) void func(x)
#define B(x) func(x)
// to define a function
A(int x) {...}
// to call a function
B(1);
```

You may see that the arguments of the two macros are totally different.
My question is, for the first situation, whether there is a solution to get different parts of the macro argument:

```
#define A(x) void func(x) { PART1(x) a = 1; std::cout << (a+PART2(x)); }
A(int x)
// will expand to:
// void func(int x) { int a = 1; std::cout << (a+x); }
func(1);
// outputs 2
```

Is it possible to implement PART1 and PART2 ?

Comment: It all depends on *your* definition of "different parts".  But the easiest solution would be to use two parameters: `A( int, x )`

Comment: @Drew Dormann. Yes, that's really easy, but I would not prefer to change the style to call the macro.

Comment: In C++11 and later, you can replace the need for `PARTx()` by using `decltype()` instead: `#define A(x) void func(x) { decltype(x) a = 1; std::cout << (a+x); }`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, will it compile for `(a+int x)`?

Comment: Remy's `decltype(x)` chokes in my testing, but you can use `{ x ## __, a = 1;` for that bit... effectively creates a dummy variable of the function parameter type as well as `a`, which will get the same type and be initialised to `1`.

Comment: @TonyD Smart. What about the latter part?

Comment: I haven't thought of any way to extract that....

Comment: @PanwenWang: yes, you're right, good catch, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is it possible to implement PART1 and PART2 ?*

Yes... sort of.  AFAIK the only way to pick out and throw away pieces of arguments separated by spaces is to apply pattern matching for one part, which should be well known and an identifier.  To fit your example, it works like this:

```
#define GLUEI(A,B) A ## B
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUEI(A,B)
#define SECONDI(_,X,...) X
#define SECOND(...) SECONDI(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PART1(A) SECOND(GLUE(EXTRACTER_,A),~)
#define PART2(A) SECOND(GLUE(SHIFTER_,A),~)
#define SHIFTER_int   ,
#define EXTRACTER_int , int ,

#define A(x) void func(x) { PART1(x) a = 1; std::cout << (a+PART2(x)); }
A(int x)
```

Everything works off of SECOND which gives you the second argument.  EXTRACTOR_foo's job is to make foo alone the second argument.  SHIFTER_foo's job is to consume foo, emit a comma, and let the rest be the second argument.  SECOND picks this argument and discards the litter produced by the matchers.

Comment: Although the type is limited (you have to know the type (int), as you define the macro `SHIFTER_int`), this is still an excellent answer. Thanks.
BTW, it doesn't work for pointer types, as `*` cannot be used as a macro name.

Comment: "BTW, it doesn't work for pointer types, as * cannot be used as a macro name"  Correct... or rephrased, it's because because "int *" isn't an identifier.  "And seems that GLUEI and GLUE work the same" ...that's idiomatic; the extra macro gives a chance for the arguments to expand before pasting.  `GLUEI(X,__LINE__)` for example produces `X__LINE__`; `GLUE(X,__LINE__)` on line 15 produces X15.  Here it's probably not strictly necessary because there's already an indirection step, but you probably want it anyway if you want to reuse the GLUE macro.